# multi-converter of units in python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python. I try to program a multi-converter of units. As well as the user request to convert 3 types of units (while loop), the program must calculate the conversion. As units to convert, I choose euro, celsius and km.

In my program below, the loop request to the user if he wants to convert something, what he wants to convert and for which value. But, then the answers of the user are not taken into consideration to calculate the conversion.

Could you please help me to correct my program below.

Thanks

```
# Set up

# Set up a boolean value for user's answers

useranswer_yes = True

# Set up a function to convert euro into CHF

# convertor factor chossed is 1.11

def euroTochf (euro):

return euro * 1.11

# Set up a function to convert degrees celsius into degrees fahrenheit

def celsiusTofahrenheit (celsius):

return (celsius *9/5) + 32

# Set up a function to convert km into miles

# convertor factor = 0.621371

def kmTomiles (km):

return km * 0.621371

# Set up input

answerConv = ""

answerType = ""

answerValue= ""

# as the user wants to convert something, a while loop must continue to ask for a conversion

while useranswer_yes != False:

answerConv = input ("Do you want to convert a value ? (yes or no)")
answerType = input ("Which type of conversion ? (euro, celsius, km)")
answerValue = input ("Which value do you want to convert ?")

# Check the user answer to convert something is yes

if answerConv =="yes":

useranswer_yes = True
# Launch the conversion calculation according to the user's answers and display the result

elif answerType =="euro":

result = "The result is" + str(euroTochf(float(answerValue)))
elif answerType =="celsius":

result = "The result is" + str(celsiusTofahrenheit(float(answerValue)))
elif answerType =="km":

result = "The result is" + str(kmTomiles(float(answerValue)))
else:

result ="I can't do this conversion"

# Display the result

print (result)
```

Comment: `elif answerType =="euro":` You should replace here `elif` with `if`: if user answers 'yes' and wants to convert, your code ignores his other input and just prints empty string, because all `elif`s are unreachable in this case.

Comment: Also note that logic is broken here, you have to replace first if with `if answerConv != "yes": useranswer_yes = False`. Otherwise your code will loop forever, useranswer_yes never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok in your answer except the indentation. Use 4 spaces before each statement inside `if..elif`